# Elasticsearch / Curl won't read newline for Bulk API

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I'm currently running windows 10, and using `curl_7_47_1_openssl_nghttp2_x64` in cmd.exe, my problem is whenever I try to input a data using bulk API in elasticsearch, I always get this error:

```
Validation Failed 1: no requests added,
```

I have already researched how to properly send data using the bulk API (add new line for every input) but `cURL` won't just read my break line statement. My full command is as follows:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/customer/external/_bulk?pretty --data-binary "{ \"index\": {\"_id\": \"1\"}} \n { \"name\": \"John Doe\" } \n {\"index\": {\"_id\": \"2\"}} \n {\"name\": \"Jane Doe\" }"
```

Additionally other information include: `cURL` doesn't read single quotes in windows and I escape the double quotes in the jSON.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two solutions:

You can store the bulk query in a file. Make sure:

- double quotes **are NOT escaped** and also
- each line (**also the last one**) ends with a newline (**NOT the newline character `\n`, but a real newline**)

`bulk.json`:

```
{"index": {"_id": "1"}}
{"name": "John Doe" }
{"index": {"_id": "2"}}
{"name": "Jane Doe" }
```

Then you can run this command

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/customer/external/_bulk?pretty --data-binary @/path/to/your/file
```

The other solution is to simply inline the same data you have but send it with the `-d` parameter instead of `--data-binary` which is used to send files.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/customer/external/_bulk?pretty -d "
{\"index\": {\"_id\": \"1\"}}
{\"name\": \"John Doe\" }
{\"index\": {\"_id\": \"2\"}}
{\"name\": \"Jane Doe\" }
"
```

Again make sure to include a newline after the last line

Comment: thank you! i tried the first one and it worked, as for the second one, i don't know how to insert inline (newline ???) in cmd.exe, but anyways thanks for the help!